# Javascript array slice basic explanation needed

Tags: javascript, slice

I learn this [Array prototype slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

This is what I tried:

```js
const animals = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'elephant'];

console.log(animals.slice(1, 2));
//outputs: ["bison"]
```

Why is this not outputting ["bison", "camel"] since the doc state it's a zero because operation?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `slice()` method selects the elements starting at the given start argument, and ends at, but does not include, the given end argument.

More info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp).

Comment: "but does not include, the given end argument." , Strange why not make it so; `console.log(animals.slice(1, 1));`

Answer (score 1):

the end is not included  more [info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from start to end (end not included) where start and end represent the index of items in that array. The original array will not be modified.